# Recover missing RAID 1 virtual drive on Dell Perc h330 controller

Tags: raid, dell-perc

Ok, I added a couple of new HDDs to a Dell t430 server.  I went to configure the new drives in a RAID1 array in the RAID controller.  I think my mistake is I went in through "Lifecycle management" instead of through setup configuration.  I told the controller I wanted to add the new virtual drive and include my two new HDDS.  That part went fine.

However, an existing virtual drive with 2 SSDs and the operating system disappeared (apparently replaced by the new virtual drive I created??). I at no time told the system to delete any existing array.

I pulled one of the existing SSDs and put it in another machine and am relieved to see my data still on it (recovering from backups would be a large operation here and it's late--and I'd lose some additional work to the backup being a few days stale).

However, I can't convince the PERC h330 to see the RAID1 virtual drive.  Any option that involves recreating the virtual drive warns that all data will be destroyed.  How do I get the RAID1 virtual drive back without losing my data?

Comment: Sounds like you got things figured out based on the answer you added. Next time around, I'd strongly recommend you use OpenManage Server Administrator for adding disks - no BIOS configuration or reboots necessary if they're in hot-swap trays!

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out the dire warning about my data being lost was a lie.  I made sure to select "No" for initialization when creating the virtual drive and after creating an image of one of the disks in another machine, I bravely clicked "Confirm" and "Yes" on the screen saying all data on the physical drives would be lost.  Despite the warning, the data was intact and I was able to boot off the new virtual drive and go on my merry way.